# Can キーウィ be used to mean New Zealander?

Tags: meaning, slang, loanwords

Outside of Australia and New Zealand, am I likely to be understood by Japanese speakers if I use キーウィ to mean New Zealanders?

Based on what [weblio](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3) and [Wiktionary](http://ja.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%BC%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A3) say, I suspect not, but I want to check as sometimes dictionaries don't mention slang terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have to say no.

「キーウィ」 refers only to the kiwifruit to at least 99% of Japanese-speakers -- perhaps even more.

Those who have lived in New Zealand or Australia ***might*** refer to a New Zealander as 「キーウィ」 among themselves, but that kind of private usage still would not count as an established meaning of the word within the Japanese language.

Comment: Except that 'kiwi fruits' are usually called キウイフルーツ - see Wikipedia https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%84

Comment: I don't think most Japanese in everyday speech will bother with the "フルーツ" part there.